# Homebrew , python installing

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, homebrew

i got an error while trying to install python throught homebrew. brew says what it failed to link python , here is output:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3... Warning: Could not link python. Unlinking...
Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/bin/smtpd2.py
/usr/local/bin/smtpd2.py may already exist.
/usr/local/bin may not be writable.
```

ls -la on /usr/bin and bin rights :

```
The drwxrwxrwx  26 root             admin  884 26 Oct 16:03 bin
```

And smtpd2.py is exists.. How can i fix it? Delete smtpd2.py ?

Comment: You /could/ `sudo rm -rf smtpd2`. But here's a bigger question: why are you using homebrew to install python? Why not just download from the [python downloads page](http://python.org/download/) directly?

Comment: I will install not only python through homebrew. Just want to use homebrew instead of macports as main package-manager.

Comment: `brew install python --universal --framework`, I installed it use this command.

Comment: yes, i installed it as you say, but at end of installation i got an error.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Sounds like a permissions issue with /usr/local.

```sh
### Makes you owner of /usr/local 
$ sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local

### Force uninstalls failed python
$ brew uninstall -f python

### Clear the brew cache
$ rm -rf `brew --cache`

### Recreate the brew cache
$ mkdir `brew --cache`

### Cleanup - cleans up old homebrew files
$ brew cleanup

### Prune - removes dead symlinks in homebrew
$ brew prune

### Doctor - runs homebrew checks for common error causing issues
$ brew doctor

########
### Google and follow steps to fix what `brew doctor` came back with
########

### Reinstall python
$ brew install python
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped to install python through homebrew:)

Comment: Im at brew doctor and getting this - can you help?  Warning: python is symlinked to python

Comment: try following the above, but running `rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/python` between the uninstall and cache clear lines

Comment: If it is a permissions issue, after fixing `/usr/local` you can also simply run `brew link python` or `brew link --overwrite python`. Using `brew link --dry-run --overwrite python` will tell you what things will change without doing it.

Comment: Thanks, `brew prune` fixed my issues!

Comment: This worked. Additionally, I had to remove /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Answer (score 21):

Did you try `brew link --overwrite python`? This worked for me without having to uninstall python - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354207/how-to-symlink-python-in-homebrew) for more details.

Comment: I had to chown /usr/local as in accepted answer, then this command worked well.

Comment: New command is `brew linkapps python` to symlink to Applications