# Homebrew Python ZSH truncation of interpreter path

Tags: python, virtualenv, homebrew, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am running python (installed through homebrew), zsh (using oh-my-zsh), and am running into issues with path truncation in scripts.

Here is one instance of the problem running pelican (a python static site generator):

```
pelican -s pelicanconf.py content -o output 
zsh: /usr/local/bin/pelican: bad interpreter: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Ver: no such file or directory
```

Naturally, I check the path of the interpreter in:

> /usr/local/bin/pelican

to verify the path. In that file the interpreter path is specified as:

```
#!/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

Has anybody experienced this issue? If so, any resolution?

If I have failed to specify necessary debug context I will happily do so.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue today, in getting pip to install while using zsh.

I think the following is the command you're looking for, I just don't know if you should put 'pelican' after overwrite or something more specific.

```
brew link --overwrite
```

I'd reference these two links to see how they relate to your issue:

[How to symlink python in Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354207/how-to-symlink-python-in-homebrew/13354417#13354417)

My issue was the very same as this first stack, and it solved my problem.