# MacOS link recent python2.7 version

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I am trying to link `python2.7` to the most recent brew install, which corresponds to `python 2.7.13`. I know of answers like this [link python with brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354207/how-to-symlink-python-in-homebrew). But it's still confusing for me.

What I need is to have `python2.7` link to `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python2.7`. I can achieve `python`
to link to `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python2.7`.

The problem is I have scripts that call `python2.7` and no matter what I do it always returns the old MacOS installation of `python2.7.5`.

I have also tried `brew link --overwrite python@2` but the same thing happens.

Ideally I would like `python` to link to `python3.6` and `python2.7` to link to `python2.7.13`

Comment: this sounds hacky but how about a `symlink` of the old python installation with the new one

Answer (score 1):

Try to use virtual environment for your script [virtual environment Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Comment: Thanks, I do use a virtualenv but this particular project created it's virtualenv so it's not up to me.

Comment: So modify the virtual env, not your system installation.