# multiple bad interpreter issues with python (even with virtualenv)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, virtualenv

I am on mac (mojave osx 10.14) and admittedly I have a pretty messed up python environment.

Recently I have been getting multiple errors such as:

```
zsh: /usr/local/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: no such file or directory

zsh: /usr/local/bin/alembic: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: no such file or directory

zsh: /usr/local/bin/pytest: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: no such file or directory
```

This is the case even with creating and entering a virtualenv to work inside of.

In this specific case, I need a python3 virtual env.

When I `which python` outside the environment, I get `/usr/local/bin/python` and `python -v` = `Python 2.7.15`

Outside this virtualenv, I get these bad interpreter errors.

I create a virtualenv for python3 with `virtualenv -p python3 .venv`

Without even installing anything, I still get

```
zsh: /usr/local/bin/alembic: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: no such file or directory

zsh: /usr/local/bin/pytest: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: no such file or directory
```

If I `pip uninstall alembic` and `pip3 uninstall alembic`, I get the bad interpreter error still.

I have no idea where it might still be installed and not sure where to start on how to clean up my environment. Would like a fresh start but I don't know if that's possible.

Answer (score 3):

You have removed (uninstalled) `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6` and the interpreter is used as the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in `/usr/local/bin/alembic`, `/usr/local/bin/pytest` and perhaps other scripts. The best way to fix them is to reinstall them with a different interpreter. For example:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip install -U alembic pip pytest
```

`/usr/bin/python3.6` is only an example here.

Comment: Yes, you're right, those files have that shebang. But, I thought if I'm working in a virtualenv, it would not be referencing those. Is there a proper way to do this to override what is in /usr/local/bin? If I specifically python3 -m pip install alembic... in the virtualenv it still gives me the same errors

Comment: You have to install copies of these modules into the virtualenv. Then you use the scripts from `venv/bin/` instead of `/usr/local/bin/`.

Answer (score 0):

My problem (Mac OS 14.4.1) was with Python 2.7 version, which was missing symlinks. I've solved it by the problem by running:

```
brew link --overwrite python
```

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354207/how-to-symlink-python-in-homebrew/13354417#13354417)