# Setting up Python venv in Mac OSX (Lion), why didn't `which python` change?

Tags: python, macos, path, osx-lion, python-venv

I'm trying to follow [this](https://github.com/nicolashery/mac-dev-setup) guide to set up Virtual Environments on OSX 10.8.5 (Lion). Homebrew is successfully installed, and the following updates completed successfully:

```
$ pip install --upgrade distribute  
$ pip install --upgrade pip
```

However, `which python` still shows `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`. Why?? (I expected `/usr/local/bin/python` instead, and the goal is to use venv(s) to separate projects.)

Updates...
$PATH information:

```
host:~ username$ echo $PATH
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/
 Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/
 sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin 
host:~ username$
```

Turns out ...
    host:~ user$ brew install python
    Updating Homebrew...
    ==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
    Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
    No changes to formulae.

```
Warning: python-2.7.13 already installed, it's just not linked.
```

Running doctor showed a number of problems, but the solution would be...
    host:~ user$ brew link python

This ultimately required a force (--overwrite) ...

For references:
    [brew install python, but then: "python-2.7.6 already installed, it's just not linked"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691181/brew-install-python-but-then-python-2-7-6-already-installed-its-just-not-li)
    [python homebrew by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157678/python-homebrew-by-default)

**However** I don't understand why this happened. If someone can explain what happened (why homebrew didn't update the link), I'm happy to award an answer.

Comment: What's in your `$PATH`?

Comment: If you haven't installed `virtualenv`, then you will need to install it first. You can use `pip install virtualenv` ( https://github.com/nicolashery/mac-dev-setup#install-1 ) Follow the guide that you posted completely

Comment: @torek $PATH info added to original question.

Comment: @pmuntima The guide states that after `brew install python` that `which python` should be updated to `/usr/local/bin/python`... (line 323)

Answer (score 0):

If your `PATH` in OS X doesn’t point to `/usr/local/bin` first, you have to set up your `virtualenv` using [the `-p` option](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#cmdoption-p), which allows you to specify the path to the python interpreter that you want to use within the `virtualenv`:

```
cd /path/to/project
virtualenv . -p /usr/local/bin/python
. bin/activate
python --version
```

Comment: Hmmm, it looked like $PATH would be updated after `brew install python` (line 323 in the tutorial)..

Comment: I can’t speak to the validity of any particular tutorial.  I can tell you that the `-p` option is what you should use to specify your python interpreter of choice.